# Unable to pass session variables to RSpec controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm testing confirmation method from a controller using RSpec, it seems like tests crush because I can't pass session variables when addressing the method.

Here's my spec:

```
RSpec.describe OauthCallbacksController, type: :controller do
  describe 'POST #confirm_email' do
    before do
      request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    end

    context 'confirms_email' do
      let(:email) { 'test-email@test.ru' }
      let(:confirm_email) { post :confirm_email, params: { email: email }, session: { auth: { uid: '12345', provider: 'facebook' } } }

      it 'redirects to new_user_session_path' do
        confirm_email
        expect(response).to redirect_to new_user_session_path
      end

      it 'sends an email' do
        expect { confirm_email }.to change{ ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count }.by(1)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Method confirm_email:

```
def confirm_email
    puts params[:email]
    pending_user = User.find_or_init_skip_confirmation(params[:email])
    if pending_user
      aut = Authorization.where(provider: session[:auth]['provider'], uid: session[:auth]['uid'], linked_email: params[:email])
                         .first_or_initialize do |auth|
        auth.user = pending_user
        auth.confirmation_token = Devise.friendly_token[0, 20],
        auth.confirmation_sent_at = Time.now.utc
      end

      if aut.save
        OauthMailer.send_confirmation_letter(aut).deliver_now
        redirect_to root_path, notice: "Great! Now confirm your email, we've sent you a letter!"
      else
        redirect_to root_path, alert: "Something went wrong. Please try again later or use another sign in method"
      end
    end
  end
```

When I try to display session variables they are `nil`, In test.log it's obvious that there should be session variables are NULL-s.

> [34mSELECT  "authorizations".* FROM "authorizations" WHERE "authorizations"."provider" IS NULL AND "authorizations"."uid" IS NULL AND "authorizations"."linked_email" = $1 ORDER BY "authorizations"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["linked_email", "test-email@test.ru"], ["LIMIT", 1]]

I use Rails 5.2.2.1 and RSpec 3.8.

I've read that in Rails 5 there's a problem accessing sessions, I've already tried setting it with `controller.session[:auth]['uid']` or
`request.session[:auth]['uid']` but nothing

Answer (score 0):

Something strange is happening in rails or rack but with a nested session, the keys are available as symbols.  This should work

```
Authorization.where(provider: session[:auth][:provider], uid: session[:auth][:uid], linked_email: params[:email])
```

Comment: Tnx, I've managed to pass session variables the different way, but I also gonna try your suggestion.

Comment: @DariaTsheglova please try and let me know so the community can benefit

Answer (score 0):

I managed to pass session parameters using `request.env["omniauth.auth"] = mock_auth_hash(:facebook)` and when instead of passing hash I've passed request to the session. It did the job.
Now my spec looks like this.

```
  describe 'POST #confirm_email' do
    before do
      request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      request.env["omniauth.auth"] = mock_auth_hash(:facebook)
      get :facebook
    end

    let(:confirm_email) { post :confirm_email, params: { email: 'mockuser@test.com'}, session: { auth: request.env["omniauth.auth"] } }

    it 'redirects to root_path' do
      confirm_email
      expect(response).to redirect_to root_path
    end

    it 'sends an email' do
      request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      request.env["omniauth.auth"] = mock_auth_hash(:facebook)
      get :facebook

      expect { confirm_email }.to change{ ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count }.by(1)
    end
  end
```